# Trying to redirect users to PHP page when they click on an embedded Vimeo video on Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, redirect, vimeo

I'm trying to post a video hosted on Vimeo on my Facebook wall, but have the users redirected to a self hosted php webpage first.

In that php webpage I send an email to myself to notify that someone clicked on the video and then redirect the user to the actual video on Vimeo.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$to      = "myemail@gmail.com";
$subject = "This is a test";
$message = "Testing";

$headers   = array();
$headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[] = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1";
$headers[] = "From: My Name <myemail@gmail.com>";
$headers[] = "Reply-To: My Name <myemail@gmail.com>";
$headers[] = "Subject: {$subject}";
$headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));

header("Location: http://www.vimeo.com/videoid");
die();
?>
```

This all works just fine on iPhone or iPad. But when I click on the video in a browser on a desktop, the embedded video just starts playing without passing through my webpage it seems.

I don't know if this is right, but my guess is Facebook looks up the url beforehand, cuts out the redirects and just uses the final link which is the Vimeo video.

So, is there any way to achieve this? Thank you in advance for any and all help.

EDIT: Some further clarification:

I paste the url to the php file in the facebook status textbox. The link automatically changes to the name and image of the Vimeo video. When I post the update and click on the video in a browser on a desktop, the video is being played embedded on Facebook. But I don't receive an e-mail. When I click on the video in the status update on an iPad or an iPhone the link opens within the browser in the Facebook app. I receive an email from the PHP page and land on the Vimeo video page.

Comment: Please add the code which you have tried.

Comment: And how do you open this PHP file/code? Do you have an event handler for when a video is clicked (in javascript or html)?

Comment: I paste the url to the php file in the facebook status textbox. The link automatically changes to the name and image of the Vimeo video. When I post the update and click on the video in a browser on a desktop, the video is being played embedded on Facebook. But I don't receive an e-mail.


When I click on the video in the status update on an iPad or an iPhone the link opens within the browser in the Facebook app. I receive an email from the PHP page and land on the Vimeo video page.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. You should add that in your question as well to avoid others closing it for "being unclear".

Comment: Your best option would be to mirror the Open Graph Tags of the Vimeo video on your page and only redirect if the user agent is not the Facebook Crawler. Also don't provide the playable media in the OG tags to avoid inline playing on FB